# Writing file to different extension (using PHP)

Tags: php, templates, file-get-contents

I have an HTM file with custom made shortcode. I plan to use a file reading function (either fgets/fputs, or file_get_content) to parse the file and then output it as a new extension.

Ex (test.htm)

```
<p>my name is [name]joe[/name]</p> and today is cool.
```

would output to
(test.tpl)

```
<p>my name is {if $name neq ''}joe{/if}<p> and today is cool.
```

I'm able to do a str_replace from reading the file, but how would I output it to a different extension?

Comment: [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/file_put_contents)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) function to write content into a file.

```
$content = file_get_contents('path/to/file'); 
$text = str_replace('<p>', '</p>', $content);    
file_put_contents($file, $text);
```

Alternatively, you can also use fopen/fwrite function to do the same.

```
$handler = fopen($file, 'w');
fwrite($handler, $text);
fclose($handler);
```